# Is a "misspelled" word which subsequently creates another word still considered misspelled?

Tags: meaning, orthography

According to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/misspelling):

> **mis·spell·ing**   [mis-spel-ing]
>   *noun*
>
> 1. the act of spelling  incorrectly: Note his misspelling of that word.
> 2. an incorrectly spelled word: You have three misspellings in your letter.

Some people have told me that as long as the letters actually create a word, it's spelled correctly. This doesn't make sense to me, though. The example I'm using occurred in a recent [Stack Exchange blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/stack-overflow-meetup-everywhere-april-28-2012/). They had accidentally typed in "word" instead of "world." I pointed out that "world" was misspelled (missing an "l") and another person said that it was technically not misspelled.

So when do we consider a word misspelled?
Only when our computer puts a red zig-zag line below it?

Isn't the word "word" still considered misspelled since it was *meant* to be "world" and it is not spelled correctly, and just happens to become a different word when this particular misspelling occurs? Is there perhaps a better definition of the word "misspelling" out there somewhere that can more accurately represent what exactly the word means?

**Note:** This isn't meant to be subjective. I'm hoping for *factual* information that supports it one way or the other.

Comment: I think your question correctly insinuates that this is a case of technology affecting our view of language. I think that "word" where "world" was meant is a misspelling.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question here is. Clearly, "word" is not the correct spelling of "world", thus it is a misspelling thereof. Whether or not it happens to be the correct spelling of *another* word, is completely irrelevant. "World" is misspelled whenever it is not spelled "world".

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道: But there are clearly people who disagree with this statement, which is *why* I asked. I could understand the reasoning behind closing this as not constructive if it became argumentative, but I failed to see how it's too localized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word you're looking for is "typo".

Comment: I think this is the distinction. A misspelling happens out of ignorance, while a typo happens out of negligence.

Comment: I'd say that a typo is just one cause of the symptom which is misspelling.  If you see only the result, it's a guess whether it's caused by carelessness or by ignorance.

Answer (score 6):

In your example, *word* isn't necessarily a misspelling. It could be that the author thinks *word* means *world* (a mistake, but not a misspelling), or is in fact saying something other than what you expected, and intended to type *word*. However, if he intended *world* and typed *word*, it's a misspelling: nowhere in the definition is there a phrase 'except where this creates a valid word in English'.